# create own message or dialog box in vb . net

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I am trying to design my own message box or dialog box.
While real message box displays, if we try to skip the messagebox by clicking the form, message box will blink thrice and shows us like we cant skip message box.

how to achieve this action in our own dialog or message box.[shared screen shot as gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1onC.gif)

Note: I am using visual studio 2017, windows application through vb .net.
I have desgined my own message or dialog box as windows form.
I have tried me.toplevel = true or me.bringfront= true

Comment: Have you tried using `Form2.ShowDialog()`, where I assume Form2 is your messagebox and Form1 is your main form?

Comment: Instead of using  "form2.show", I want to use "form2.showdialog" ?

Comment: Fine that works great! Thanks team

Comment: This code works as dialog or message box succeeded. but blinking form like that is it possible?

Comment: A normal Windows Form would blink when selected as a dialog and would blink if clicked outside it. However, if you have a customised Windows Form such as a form based on MetroFramework, it would not blink and would only produce the sound effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form.ShowDialog` it prevents user interaction with the form in the back